# What is the significance of the call sign on the Area 51 Spaceship?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Just for fun....

I notice on the [Area 51 page for a proposal in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel), there is a graphic of a spaceship whose call sign is "USS-SE-1701":

[image: The Starship Stack Exchange?]

What is the significance of "1701"?

Comment: Presumably the SE is for stackexchange?

Comment: This is a question for http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number 1701 is a reference to the [USS *Enterprise*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701%29) of Star Trek fame, which is designated NCC-1701 in the original canon.

Of course, NCC is replaced with SE, which stands for Stack Exchange. After all, that rocket looks nothing like the *Enterprise* :)